# System.Cursor = wdCursorWait does not work on word 365

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to show a glasshour while my VBA is running. I did try the `System.Cursor = wdCursorWait` and `System.Cursor = wdCursorNormal` code that used to run smoothly on earlier version of word, but does not seem to work anymore in Word 365. Can someone help?

Comment: Does it change anything if you add `DoEvents` after that?

Comment: Not really. I never did such a thing. Actually, i tried a Do While procedure like this 
 s = 1
    Do While s = 1
    System.Cursor = wdCursorWait  s = s + 1
    Loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Cursor = wdCursorWait
DoEvents
...
System.Cursor = wdCursorNormal
DoEvents
```

Tested in Word 365. Somewhat slow to respond, possibly due to the sandboxing, but works reliably.

Comment: Thanks Timothy and Gserg, adding DoEvents do the tricks

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have Microsoft Office LTSC Professional Plus 2021. Microsoft® Word LTSC MSO (Version 2211 Build 16.0.15831.20098) 64-bit.